# Why is it that for a unital $C^*$-algebra any positive linear functional $\varphi$ must be such that $\|\varphi\| =\varphi()$?

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

I understand that this is a consequence of a related, more general theorem for non-unital $C^*$-algebras, where we can find approximants of a unit, but for the simple case of a unital $C^*$-algebra $\mathscr{A}$ , what is the simple argument that implies that positive linear functionals $\varphi:\mathscr{A} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ (defined as $\varphi(a^*a) \geq 0, \forall \, a \in \mathscr{A}$) are such that $\|\varphi\| =\varphi(\mathbf 1)$ ?

Comment: The question seems a bit ambiguous - do you want a proof that a positive linear functional $\varphi$ must satisfy $\|\varphi\| = \varphi(1)$ (which is what Kroki proved in their answer), or the converse of this, or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First $\varphi(\mathbf 1) \le \left\|\varphi\right\| \left\|\mathbf 1\right\| = \left\|\varphi\right\|$. For the reverse, we start with the following claim:

> If $a\in\mathcal A$ is self-adjoint then $$\varphi (a) \in \mathbb R\quad \text{and} \quad \left|\varphi(a)\right| \le \left\|a\right\| \varphi\left(\mathbf 1\right)$$

*Proof:* Since $\left\|a\right\|\mathbf 1 \succeq a \succeq - \left\|a\right\|\mathbf 1$ then by linearity and positivity of $\varphi$, $$\left\|a\right\|\varphi\left(\mathbf 1\right) \ge \varphi(a) \ge -\left\|a\right\|\varphi(\mathbf 1)$$

---

Now we are back to the general case, let $a\in \mathcal A$ (not mandatory self-adjoint),

\begin{align}
\left|\varphi\left(a\right)\right|^2 &= \left|\varphi\left(\mathbf 1^* a\right)\right|^2\\
&\le \varphi(\mathbf 1)\left|\varphi\left(a^*a\right)\right| &&(\text{Cauchy-Schwarz})\\
&\le \varphi\left(\mathbf 1\right)\left\|a^* a\right\|\varphi\left(\mathbf 1\right) &&(\text{Apply the claim on $a^*a$})\\
&= \varphi(\mathbf 1)^2\left\|a\right\|^2 &&(\text{using $\left\|a^*a\right\| = \left\|a\right\|^2$)}
\end{align}

This proves that $\left\|\varphi\right\| \le \varphi(\mathbf 1)$.

Comment: Why is it that $\|a\| \mathbf{1} \succcurlyeq a \succcurlyeq -\|a\| \mathbf{1}$ ? Actually, what does that even mean? Is it that $\|a\| \mathbf{1} - a$ is a positive element, for example?

Comment: @FelipeDilho For operators, $a \geq b$ usually means $a - b$ is a positive operator.

Comment: @FelipeDilho yes it means exactly that the difference is a positive element

Comment: @Kroki Isn't the limitation of $a$ being self-adjoint too limiting for the implication that $\|\varphi\| \leq \varphi(\mathbf{1})$ to follow from $|\varphi(a)|^2 \leq \varphi(\mathbf{1})^2 \|a\|^2$ ? What guarantees that there is no pesky non-self-adjoint b such that $\frac{|\varphi(b)|}{\|b\|} > \frac{|\varphi(a)|}{\|a\|}$ for any self-adjoint $a$ ?

Comment: I added some edits. You can see if that solves your concerns.

Comment: Ah, ok, thank you!